# Showing Difference between two datetime values in hours

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, datetime, timespan

I am retrieving two date time values from the database. Once the value is retrieved, I need the difference between the two values.
For that, I create a timespan variable to store the difference of the 2 date values.

```
TimeSpan? variable = datevalue1 - datevalue2;
```

Now i need to show the difference which is stored in the Timespan variable in terms of number of hours.
I referred to [TimeSpan.TotalHours](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours.aspx) but couldn't apply the same for some reason.
How do I do that?
I am using C# on a MVC project. I simple need to show the difference value in hours?

**EDIT:
Since timespan was nullable, i couldn't use the total hours property. Now I can use it by doing TimeSpanVal.Value.TotalHours**;

Comment: Why could you not use `TimeSpan.TotalHours`?

Comment: it doesnt allow me to. i tried. :(

Comment: is it because my timespan is nullable that i cannot use the totalhours property?

Comment: See example of datetime difference, Hours Difference, Minutes difference on http://www.codegateway.com/2012/01/c-datetime-difference.html

Comment: the TimeSpan object has total hours in `.Value.TotalHours`

Answer (score 136, accepted):

I think you're confused because you haven't declared a `TimeSpan` you've declared a `TimeSpan?` which is a [nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.80).aspx) `TimeSpan`. Either remove the question mark if you don't need it to be nullable or use `variable.Value.TotalHours`.

Answer (score 275):

you may also want to look at

```
var hours = (datevalue1 - datevalue2).TotalHours;
```

Comment: but in this case system shows " 'System.Nullable<System.TimeSpan>' does not contain a definition for 'TotalHours' and no extension method 'TotalHours' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable<System.TimeSpan>' could be found ". Can you please tell me the reason for it?

Comment: Nullable would need a .Value.TotalHours instead of just .TotalHours.  It's a factor of the nullable wrapping.  You could alternatively cast it as a timespan --> ((TimeSpan) (nullabledatevalue1 - nullabledatevalue2)).TotalHours

Answer (score 125):

In the sample, we are creating two datetime objects, one with current time and another one with 75 seconds added to the current time. Then we will call the method .Subtract() on the second DateTime object. This will return a TimeSpan object.
Once we get the TimeSpan object, we can use the properties of TimeSpan to get the actual Hours, Minutes and Seconds.

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;

 DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds( 75 );

 TimeSpan span = endTime.Subtract ( startTime );
 Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (seconds): " + span.Seconds );
 Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (minutes): " + span.Minutes );
 Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (hours): " + span.Hours );
 Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (days): " + span.Days );
```

Result:

```
Time Difference (seconds): 15
Time Difference (minutes): 1
Time Difference (hours): 0
Time Difference (days): 0
```

Comment: You want to use "Total" such as `TotalSeconds`, `TotalMinutes` etc

Answer (score 41):

Is there a reason you're using `Nullable`?

If you want to use `Nullable` then you can write `variable.Value.TotalHours`.

Or you can just write: `(datevalue1 - datevalue2).TotalHours`.

Comment: Probably because datevalue1 or datevalue2 are `DateTime?`

Comment: @Filip, it's ok, they should be `DateTime`. In .NET, `DateTime - DateTime = TimeSpan`.

Comment: @Illya, I mean that They are probably `Nullable<DateTime>` and therefore you get a `Nullable<TimeSpan>`.

Comment: Your answer is really effective. I was looking for it.

Answer (score 8):

Here is another example of subtracting two dates in C# ...

```
if ( DateTime.Now.Subtract(Convert.ToDateTime(objDateValueFromDatabase.CreatedOn)).TotalHours > 24 ) 
{ 
... 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**a more precise way for employee paid hours or other precision requirement:**:

```
decimal DeterminePreciseHours(DateTime startTimestamp, DateTime stopTimestamp)
{
    var span = (stopTimestamp - startTimestamp).Value;
    decimal total = (decimal)span.TotalMilliseconds / 60 / 60 / 1000;
    return Math.Round(total, PRECISION_CONSTANT);
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/tVIoVJ

Answer (score 2):

```
var startTime = new TimeSpan(6, 0, 0); // 6:00 AM
var endTime = new TimeSpan(5, 30, 0); // 5:30 AM 
var hours24 = new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0);
var difference = endTime.Subtract(startTime); // (-00:30:00)
difference = (difference.Duration() != difference) ? hours24.Subtract(difference.Duration()) : difference; // (23:30:00)
```

can also add difference between the dates if we compare two different dates

```
new TimeSpan(24 * days, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

WOW, I gotta say: keep it simple:

```
MessageBox.Show("Result: " + (DateTime.Now.AddDays(10) > DateTime.Now));

Result: True
```

and:

```
MessageBox.Show("Result: " + DateTime.Now.AddDays(10).Subtract(DateTime.Now));

Result: 10.00:00:00
```

The DateTime object has all the builtin logic to handle the Boolean result.