# How to subtract a datetime from another datetime?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

How do I subtract two DateTime values from another DateTime value and have the result saved to a double?

Comment: The result in what unit of time? Ticks? Seconds? Any example input/output?

Comment: What's this  what should be the the output after subtracting

Comment: Related post - [Showing Difference between two datetime values in hours](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4946316/465053)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In .NET, if you subtract one `DateTime` object from another, you will get a `TimeSpan` object. You can then use the `Ticks` property on that `TimeSpan` object to get the number of ticks between the two `DateTime` objects. However, the ticks will be represented by a `Long`, not a `Double`.

```
DateTime date1;
DateTime date2;
Long diffTicks = (date2 - date1).Ticks;
```

There are other interesting properties on the `TimeSpan` object like `TotalMilliseconds` and `TotalMinutes` and things like that which can help you out, and may be more what you are looking for.

Answer (score 26):

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now; 
DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds( 75 );  
TimeSpan span = endTime.Subtract ( startTime ); 
Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (seconds): " + span.TotalSeconds ); 
Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (minutes): " + span.TotalMinutes ); 
Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (hours): " + span.TotalHours ); 
Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (days): " + span.TotalDays );
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you need.

```
DateTime d1 = DateTime.Now;
DateTime d2 = DateTime.UtcNow;

var result = d1 - d2;

double dResult = result.Ticks;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [DateTime.Subtract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby.aspx) which will return TimeSpan , then use TotalSeconds property of the result which is of type double.

Answer (score 1):

```
var Date1 = new DateTime(2018, 12, 15);
var Date2 = new DateTime(2019, 1, 1);
TimeSpan result1 = Date2.Subtract(Date1);
Console.WriteLine(result1);

//To calculate difference between two dates use TotalDays() method
double result2 = Date2.Subtract(Date1).TotalDays;
Console.WriteLine(result2);

//Output:
17.00:00:00
17
```

### Note:

- Date2 should be greater than Date1 or else the method will return a negative value
- Subtract() method returns value of type **TimeSpan** while TotalDays() method returns value of type **double**

Answer (score 0):

You should try in this.

```
DateTime prevDate = DateTime.Parse("25-Feb-2011 12:30");
double subDouble = DateTime.Now.Ticks - prevDate.Ticks;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is you want to store 
if you need a double

```
  double difference = date2.ToOADate() - date1.ToOADate();
```