# How to subtract one DateTime from Another and return a double of hours passed

Tags: c#, datetime

So I have two DateTimes:
date1 = 1/1/2000 12:00:00 AM
date2 = 1/1/2000 12:30:00 AM

How can I subtract date2 from date1 and return a double of .5?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to subtract a datetime from another datetime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177002/how-to-subtract-a-datetime-from-another-datetime)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can subtract one `DateTime` from another using the `-` operator (or use the [`Subtract`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby.aspx) method) to get a `TimeSpan`, then use [`TimeSpan.TotalHours`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours.aspx):

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime end = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 30, 0);
TimeSpan difference = end - start;
Console.WriteLine(difference.TotalHours); // 0.5
```

Note that you do *not* want [`TimeSpan.Hours`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.hours.aspx), which returns an `int` in the range -23 to 23 (inclusive); it's the "whole" number of hours.

Comment: This won't return an int?  I was under the impression TimeSpan only returned int's.

Comment: @AlWoods: Just follow the link to the documentation... (`Hours` returns an `int`; `TotalHours` returns a `double`.)

Comment: Ah.  thats where the confusion is coming from!  I'll accept asap

Comment: Tried to fix typo in code (TimeStamp -> TimeSpan) but couldn't because "edits must be at least 6 characters".

Answer (score 0):

To get the double you have to use `TimeSpann.TotalHours`, as Suggested by Jon Skeet:

```
TimeSpan timeSpann = date2 - date1;
Double difference = timeSpann.TotalHours;
```

[TimeSpann.TotalHours](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)