# Subtracting DateTime.Now from a Value in a Sql column

Tags: c#, sql

I am working on converting some code and I am no longer using `Recordsets` and I am using `datasets` with `SqlClient` namespace. The code below is what I am trying to convert (ADODB to SqlClient). The `datatype` in SQL is `datetime`. Could I use a `data table` in place of a recordset? What is the best way to approach this? I did find a similar post  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177002/how-to-subtract-a-datetime-from-another-datetime) but its doesnt fully answer my question.

```
else if (DateTime.Now - rs.Fields["time_of_lock"].Value < TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15))
```

Comment: .NET never had recordsets. It was DataTables or data readers from the start.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Check [Here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9a81a4/adodb-connection-in-net-application-using-C-Sharp/)

Comment: The solution to your problem is to delete any code using ADODB and use ADO.NET. Hackers read SO too and use such vulnerabilities to find targets. If you think that's an exaggeration, check [Preventing the Top Security Weaknesses Found in Stack Overflow Code Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/12/02/preventing-the-top-security-weaknesses-found-in-stack-overflow-code-snippets/) from SO's own blog. Whoever uses that article's code doesn't just have a very slow application. They put on a t-shirt saying "Hack Me"

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Which is exactly what I am trying to do. SqlClient is under the ADO.net umbrella. So why did I get a down vote when I clearly stated in my question I am converting old code this is currently ADODB to SqlClient ?

Comment: Is there a chunk of new code that you've tried that is not working?

Comment: @Learning2Code The issue i am running into is subtracting `datetime` from the value in `SQL`. Im not sure how to go about it using `SqlClient`

Comment: I think https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5771/querying-sql-server-tables-from-net/ is a good place for you to start.

Comment: If you are more concerned with handling things on the C# side, try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataadapters-and-datareaders  and/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619216/reading-a-date-using-datareader

Comment: @Rich412 if you use ADO.NET and a call to [DbCommand.ExecuteReader()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbcommand.executereader?view=netframework-4.8) you can get a reader and read dates directly with [DbDataReader.GetDateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbdatareader.getdatetime?view=netframework-4.8). That's how people have been working for 19 years, and what all .NET tutorials show since 2002.