# Difference between 2 DateTimes in Hours?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Showing Difference between two datetime values in hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946316/showing-difference-between-two-datetime-values-in-hours)

Hi,

is there an easy way to get the difference between 2 DateTime-Values in Hours?

I know, its a possibility to calculate itself by get for each day difference 24h, for each month 188h and so on... but is there an easy way given mybe?

Example:

```
1) 01.02.2010 12:00
2) 03.03.2011 14:00
```

= ? Hours differnce

Comment: In what way does every month have 188 hours?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

It's pretty simple:

```
TimeSpan diff = secondDate - firstDate;
double hours = diff.TotalHours;
```

Note that if these `DateTime` values have been taken *locally*, the results may not be the number of *elapsed* hours. For example, you could have one `DateTime` of midnight and one of 2am, but only one hour had elapsed - because the clocks went forward at 1am. This may or may not be an issue for you. It won't be a problem if you're dealing with UTC `DateTime` values.

Answer (score 8):

`(dateTime1-dateTime2).TotalHours` will give a double with the total difference in hours between the two.

Comment: It is not working in C#4.5, subtracting dates returns object of DateTime not TimeSpan

Answer (score 5):

```
date1.Subtract(date2).TotalHours
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TimeSpan difference = firstDateTime - secondDateTime;
double diffInHours = difference.TotalHours
```

Comment: But i think its true that if " TimeSpan difference = secondDateTime -firstDateTime ;" !

Comment: @combo_ci depends entirely on what you're trying to do. Neither firstDateTime nor secondDateTime dicated which was the earlier or later, nor whether diffInHours would be positive or negative, nor which was was required. It's a generic example of using TimeSpan arithmetic

Answer (score 1):

[DateTime.Subtract(DateTime)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby.aspx) will return a TimeSpan that has a TotalHours property.

Comment: Except that you don't want to use the Hours property, because that's limited to -23 to 23.

Comment: Indeed, TotalHours would probably be better :)