# How to get a time span between two methods in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, class, console-application, stopwatch

I am trying to make a stopwatch with C# as an exercise for myself. my plan was to make two methods " start()" and " stop()" then call these from my stopwatch class in my main. the problem I have is that I do not know how to get the time span between these two.

for your information, this is how I want the program to work: if they typed s the timer starts and when press enter or type f the time will be shown to them.

this is the code I have written so far, but got stuck when getting the time span.

```
 class StopWatch
{
    DateTime starting = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime finishing = DateTime.Now;
    
    
    public void start()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(starting);
    }

    public void stop()
    {
      
        Console.WriteLine(finishing);
    }

    
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("type s to start and f to stop");
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        var stopwatch = new StopWatch();
        if (input.ToLower() == "s") { stopwatch.start(); }
        var Input2 = Console.ReadLine();
        if (Input2.ToLower() == "f") { stopwatch.stop(); }

        

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not create your own class. Use Stopwatch from .net library. All methods are there.

Comment: @OptionalOption   You are right, that can be done and I saw many tutorials about how to do it that way but currently, I am studying about classes in C# and this is one of the exercises. that's why I want to solve it this way. appreciate your comment though .:)

Comment: Just `Elapsed = finishing - starting;` in the Stop. It is a [TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.timespan)

Comment: You can use TimeSpan in c# which will give the difference b/w two dates. For example TimeSpan ts = t2-t1; here t2 and t1 are dates

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing Difference between two datetime values in hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946316/showing-difference-between-two-datetime-values-in-hours)

Comment: I forgot: in the `Stop` set `Finished = DateTime.Now`. Also you can create a property to read `Elapsed` in realtime instead that returns `DateTime.Now - Started` if running else  `Finished - Started`. You will need a field `bool Running`. On Start you can continue and Restart reset the Stared to Now. Thus you can do pauses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with the comment to use what already exists in the library, but since you said you are doing this as an exercise, here is some feedback:

To answer you direct question how to get a TimeSpan:
`var duration = finishing - starting;`

The current implementation will not do what you intend to do, since you set both `starting` and `finishing` at object creation time: field initializers are executed before any constructor code. So you should set `starting` in the `start()` method and `finishing` in the `stop()` method. Then you can calculate the duration as shown above in the `stop()` method, too.

And allow me a little side note on naming: "*starting*" and "*finishing*" are progressive forms in English, but here you want to name specific values. Therefore I'd recommend "*startTime*" and "*endTime*"/"*stopTime*".