# How to subtract timespan to get correct timedifference

Tags: c#

How to calculate correctly timedifference between two time to show correctly number days hours minutes. The code I wrote shows wrong time span. As I show on the following picture:

[image]

My code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  TimeSpan ts = dateTimePicker2.Value - dateTimePicker1.Value;
  textBox1.Text = ts.ToString();

  string total = textBox1.Text;
  string[] TotalTIme = textBox1.Text.Split('.');
  textBox1.Text = TotalTIme[0];
}
```

Comment: You keep rewriting textBox1. Plus the ToString for a TimeSpan has several formatting options

Comment: All you have to do is specify the format. `textBox1.Text = ts.ToString("dd days hh hours");` (I leave it up to you to investigate the formatting).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing Difference between two datetime values in hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946316/showing-difference-between-two-datetime-values-in-hours)

Answer (score 3):

The title of your question is misleading since you actually know how to subtract times to get the `TimeSpan`, but you don't know how to get the desired information out of it.

You can use `TimeSpan.ToString` with a [custom format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings) like:

```
string result = ts.ToString("dd' days, 'hh' hours and 'mm' minutes'");
```

Note that you also have to quote the spaces as shown above.

If you want the day, hour and minutes as "pure" values, use the appropriate [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=net-6.0#properties).

Comment: Tiny detail: the `@` is not necessary.

Comment: @Andrew: you're right, removed